# How to handle comfirm alert in Playwright python

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I was struggling to how to handle alert box in playwright, I was following this documentation https://playwright.dev/python/docs/dialogs#alert-confirm-prompt-dialogs

Here is my snippet of code

```
page.click('text=STOP BUTTON'); #Prompt appears are you sure you want to stop? xOK xCancel
page.on("dialog", lambda dialog: dialog.accept())
page.on("dialog", lambda dialog: print(dialog.message))

page.click("OK")
#page.click('text=OK')
```

Comment: Any log, any error trace? Where is the issue?

Comment: The alert box appears for a second and goes away! It doesn't clicks on OK button in dialog box.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What `dialog.accept()` does is to `accept` (click OK) the dialog.
`page.click("OK")` only works with DOM (HTML) elements, not with browser dialogs.

Comment: For some odd reason I can't see alert box too!

Comment: @morty7676 did you try removing `page.on("dialog", lambda dialog: dialog.accept())` ?

Answer (score 0):

before of all, put the `page.on` parts before the click as below:

```
page.on("dialog", lambda dialog: print(dialog.message))
page.on("dialog", lambda dialog: dialog.accept())
page.click('text=STOP BUTTON')
```

and then remove the `page.click("OK")` because when you accept the dialog with `dialog.accept()` the alert will be removed automatically.